# Django saving file to different model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a simple form which is used for submitting files which worked fine. I've since moved the file out from a field into its own table, now I'm really struggling as I need to add the file to the extra table and save the correct foreignkey in the form table. I've tried various snippets in save(), grabbing the file in the view and adding the file as an extra field but nothing is quite working.

The fairly obvious error is:

> "Cannot assign InMemoryUploadedFile: Resource.file must be a File
>   instance"

```
class File(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField('Filename', max_length=200)
    file = models.FileField()
    mimetype = models.CharField('Mimetype', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.filename

class Resource(models.Model):
    list_display = ('title', 'approved')

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.title)

    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField('Description', null=True)
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    ... cut for brevity

class ResourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Resource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you assign a file into a foreign key field. You need to instantiate the `File` object first and then set in to `Resource` object.

```
file = File(filename="test", file=temp_data, mimetype='pdf')
file.save()
resource.file = file
resource.save()
```

Comment: Ha! I'd given up and "hacked" it in which is the way you've shown above, so that's good news that it's not a completely silly way to do it.